# RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system

Tags: python, docker, amazon-ec2, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to build a docker image that requires GPU CUDA access. I am using an AWS EC2 p2.xlarge instance that supposedly has the correct hardware. My Dockerfile is building but when running my code, PyTorch can't find CUDA.

`print(torch.__version__, torch.cuda.is_available())`

returns

`1.10.0+cu113 False`

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-opencv ca-certificates python3-dev git wget sudo ninja-build
RUN ln -sv /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# Update apt packages
RUN apt update
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install git

# Install pip
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir awscli
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install wheel
RUN pip install setuptools
RUN pip install pip install nvidia-ml-py3

############ Detectron2 pre-built binaries Pytorch default install ############
RUN pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cu113 torchvision==0.11.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
RUN pip install cython

RUN pip install --user 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore'

RUN pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'

ARG magma-cuda112
RUN if [ -z "$MAGMA_CUDA_VERSION" ] ; then \
    echo "Building with CPU support ..."; \
    else \
    echo "Building with GPU/CUDA support ..."; \
    conda install -y -c pytorch ${MAGMA_CUDA_VERSION} && conda clean -ya; \
    fi

# set FORCE_CUDA because during `docker build` cuda is not accessible
ENV FORCE_CUDA="1"
# This will by default build detectron2 for all common cuda architectures and take a lot more time,
# because inside `docker build`, there is no way to tell which architecture will be used.
ARG TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="3.7+PTX;5.0;6.0;6.1;7.0;7.5;8.0;8.6"
ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="${TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST}"

COPY . .
RUN aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file/model.pth ./output
CMD [ "python", "impaction_detection.py" ]
```

I am trying to build this image using a docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: The machine image you select for the p2.xlarge instance matters also.  You cannot set up the machine completely from the container unless you get quite a bit more complicated than what you are doing now.  So my guess is that the machine image you are using for that instance does not have proper support built in for the GPU hardware.  If you were thinking that you could handle the driver dependency from your container, you can't.  The driver has to be properly installed in the base machine (image) first.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella,
I'm using one of the deep learning base images. I think it's Deep Learning AMI (Amazon Linux 2) Version 55.0 or Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 53.0.

I have run my code before without using Docker. I need to just dockerize my models to deploy to ECS.

My guess is that I need to install CUDA in the Dockerfiles. No idea how to though. Been a tough couple of days hacking.

Comment: this: `FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04` already has CUDA installed.  Maybe the GPU driver in that AMI is [too old](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-base.html) to work with your CUDA version in the docker container.

Comment: @RobertCrovella that would make a lot of sense. When I run ```nvcc --version``` the response is ```nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_22_19:09:09_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.221
Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0```

I changed the base of the docker file to ```FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu18.04``` , but it's still not working...

Any other ideas?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I've seemed to fix it by adding ```runtime: nvidia``` to my docker-compose file. I now get True when running ```print(torch.__version__, torch.cuda.is_available())```.  My new error is ```RuntimeError: CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable```. Do you know what this may mean?

Answer (score 4):

For Google Collab only: Just click on RAM/Disk(this will appear once your notebook is connected) button on the notebook and change the runtime type to t4gpu, this will work and your epoch will run way faster.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error from google colab. if you got from there check your sources first. if there is no gpu you can not use gpu for training your model. Therefore, you need to select cpu to train the model.

for detectron2:

```
cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = 'cpu'
...
```

It worked.

Comment: I found another solution you can add gpu to your google colab by changing some settings.

Comment: Nice, is there a way to tell it to use more than one CPUs (cores)?

Comment: `cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = 'cpu'  # set device to CPU
cfg.DATALOADER.NUM_WORKERS = 4  #  tell the program to use 4 cores.`               @szabgab This should work but I want to remind you that it will be an extremely slow and painful process both for you and your computer.

Comment: Thanks @beton. Yes I know. On my development computer I don't have a GPU. So there I'd use a very minimal process (few iterations) that will only create a bad model. This is part of a system that would then create some predictions and I'd like to be able to see the whole process even if the results are not useful.